# How to find duplicated values in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to find duplicate values in a javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array)

How do you find duplicated values in an array?

```
var arr = ['manager','manager','employee','manager',
           'director','employee','manager','operatives'];
```

Im looking to get the values that were duplicated to return in an array, in this case `manager` and `employee`, so the return value will be `['manager','employee']`.

Comment: Does it need to work for strings only, or for all types of values?

Comment: For your exact needs this may work: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/6yFEC/.

Comment: @pimvdb thanks thats the answer i was looking for

Comment: @pimvdb, @\manraj82: that solution needs a shim to work in IE 8 and lower.